# Concatenating custom list wrapper data type

Tags: haskell

I have the following data type.

```
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]
```

Unfortunately, creating samples of this datatype is quite unwieldy.

```
List [Elem 5, Elem 6, Elem 7, List [Elem 8, Elem 9, Elem 10]]
```

I would like to create a helper `fromList` that will take a flat array of any type and give back a NestedList which is also flat but contains the same data. So I could make the sample above (excluding the part where it begins to nest) using the helper in this way:

```
fromList [5, 6, 7] == List [Elem 5, Elem 6, Elem 7]
```

This is what I have so far.

```
fromList :: [a] -> NestedList a
fromList [] = List[]
fromList [a] = Elem a
fromList (x:xs) = List [Elem x] ++ List [fromList xs]
```

The error messages are:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’ with actual type ‘NestedList a’
• In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘List [Elem x]’


• Couldn't match expected type ‘NestedList a’ with actual type ‘[a0]’
• In the expression: List [Elem x] ++ List [fromList xs]
```

I'm not sure why it's telling me that I'm not returning a `NestedList`. I guess Haskell does not know how to natively concat my new type `NestedList`? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

++ is defined only for [a].  You can:

```
fromList :: [a] -> NestedList a
fromList [a] = Elem a
fromList x = List $ fmap Elem x
```

Though I do not know why you want a special case for only one element list.

Answer (score 4):

You have already specified what you need quite well with your equation

```
fromList [5, 6, 7] == List [Elem 5, Elem 6, Elem 7]
```

If we just abstract

```
fromList xs = List (xs but with Elem applied to each element)
```

that is,

```
fromList xs = List (map Elem xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only use `++` on regular Haskell lists, not on the custom thing you made. Instead of `List [Elem x] ++ List [fromList xs]`, do `List ([Elem x] ++ [fromList xs])`. Or since that's just two elements, simplify it as `List [Elem x, fromList xs]`.